# Author of "military squad" SF podcast

Tags: authors

I'm trying to track down an author whose audiobook podcasts I listened to around 2008.
The story was a military SF about a team of soldiers or mercenaries.
I think it was on Podiobooks.
I think he is English.
He has also written a wider variety of SF published, at least, as ebooks.
He may also have contributed to computer games.
I think his name may sound Serbian or Bosnian because I keep getting him confused with Steve Rasnic Tem.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example? - I can't see I've missed anything relevant.

Comment: Well, off the top of my head, it would be useful it you could remember any of the titles or chapter titles, what the setting was (aliens/future/alt-present-day), who any of the characters were, what their motivation was, who they were fighting, what weapons they were using, what weapons/motivation/etc their enemies had, whether the enemies had any distinctive characters, whether this was aimed at adults (with sex/violence), etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you may be thinking of [Andy Remic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Remic).

This is a British author who has written some other fiction, including SF thrillers and a steampunk(ish) fantasy called the Clockwork Vampires.

There is a link to his blog from [2008](https://andyremic.blogspot.com/2008/10/war-machine-podcast-now-live.html), where it mentions that he is going to be reading one of his "Combat K" series of novel, on Podiobooks.

Combat K is a series of 4 (currently) novels set in a post singularity universe that follows the exploits of a former elite military unit lead by Keenan, along with his squadmates Pippa and Franco.  The book mentioned in the link for the podcast is War Machine, the first in the Combat K series:

Extract from the podcast link website

> > WAR MACHINE-
> > In a time of post-Singularity and FTL travel, Combat K are elite and murderous combat squads trained by the Quad-Gal Military specialising in interrogation, infiltration, assassination and detonation. Their gameplan is simple: to end The Helix War, which had raged across galaxies for a thousand years.
> > Ex-soldier Keenan, a stocky battered war veteran, addicted to Jataxa spirit yet still horribly efficient at his job, is working as a private investigator on a planet at the peaceful fringes of the Quad-Gal. Following the death of his family, Keenan is riddled with guilt and self-loathing, and carries a need for revenge which consumes him. When a prince from Jervai Province offers him a case on a dangerous colony world in exchange for clues that may lead to his family's murderer, Keenan is dragged from his self-pity. However, to have any chance of success he must gather together his old military unit, a group who swore they'd never work together again...
> > Through the tribal jungles of Ket, the mean chaotic streets of The City, the mission leads the squad to Teller's World, a Dead World, and home of the extinct God Leviathan... and there Keenan will find answers to his deepest nightmares... and face an ancient, evil terror older than The Four Galaxies.

Further with the mention of the name of the author getting confused with being Serbian or Bosnian, then I think that the surname Remic fits very well.

Comment: Thanks! That’s it. Very fast!

Comment: I got a phone call from Andy Remic early this year, he has serious health issues